# Directory Map in CodeIgniter - Not working with Integers as directory names

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory, helper

When using the directory_map Helper in CodeIgniter I am unable to get the directory names if they are a straight integer. For example "2013" won't work. But "2013_test" will work.

An example of a print_r that I have is below. As is the line of code to directory_map

Is there a fix for this?

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
    )

[2] => Array
    (
    )

[3] => Array
    (
    )

[4] => Array
    (
    )

[5] => Array
    (
    )

[6] => Array
    (
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2010.pdf
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2011.pdf
        [1] => 2011.xls
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2012.pdf
        [1] => 2012.xls
    )
```

)

$publication_data = dir_map_sort(directory_map($pre_string.$uri_string."/", 2));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this. You have to modify the directory_map function in the array_helper file. I've clearly commented at the start and end of the code I have added in.

```
if ( ! function_exists('directory_map'))
{

function directory_map($source_dir, $directory_depth = 0, $hidden = FALSE)
{

    if ($fp = @opendir($source_dir))
    {
        $filedata   = array();
        $new_depth  = $directory_depth - 1;
        $source_dir = rtrim($source_dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;   

        while (FALSE !== ($file = readdir($fp)))
        {
            // Remove '.', '..', and hidden files [optional]
            if ( ! trim($file, '.') OR ($hidden == FALSE && $file[0] == '.'))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (($directory_depth < 1 OR $new_depth > 0) && @is_dir($source_dir.$file))
            {
                //code added - mike lovely (it's just this if/else below)
                if(($file >= "1970") && ($file <= "2300")) { 
                    $file_1 = "_".$file; 
                }else{ 
                    $file_1 = $file; 
                }
                //end - mike lovely
                $filedata[$file_1] = directory_map($source_dir.$file.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $new_depth, $hidden);
            }
            else
            {
                $filedata[] = $file;
            }
        }

        closedir($fp);
        return $filedata;

    }

    return FALSE;
}
}
```

This will put an underscore character at the start of your array name.

I combined this with an ltrim($array_name,"_") in my model to take it back off before passing it back to the controller.

Hope this helps.